# Is there a way to tell Smarty not to print an expression?

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty, zend-framework-mvc, pimcore

I'd like to use Smarty in conjuction with the Zend Framework, especially some of it's View Helpers.
Now i got to the point, where i implemented a Zend_View that uses Smarty to display templates. I can assign values as usual. So far so good.

Now I would really like to use Zend View Helpers in Smarty. I asssigned the Zend_View object as "this" and tried this in the template:

```
{$this->layout()->setLayout('default')}
```

As this will print the return value of the setLayout() method (which is a Zend_Layout), there is an error:

**Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend_Layout could not be converted to string in /path/to/templates_c/089c3d67082722c7cabc028fa92a077f8d8b4af5.file.default.tpl.cache.php on line 27**

This is clear to me, so I went into Smarty's core to fix this:

The generated code did look like this:

```
<?php 
    echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['this']
                     ->value->layout()
                     ->setLayout('default');
?>
```

And now it reads:

```
<?php
    $hack = $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['this']
                          ->value
                          ->layout()
                          ->setLayout('default');
    if( is_string($hack) ||
        ( is_object($hack) && method_exists($hack, '__toString') ) )
        echo $hack;
?>
```

Now this is probably the worst fix i can think of, for several reasons (Smarty compatibility loss, performance). Sadly, it's the only one. Is there a way to stop Smarty from trying to print the output of the expression? Also, i want the syntax to stay as intuitive as possible, and i don't want to write Smarty functions for all the Helpers, because I want to use this code with a third-party application (Pimcore) that might add new helpers.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Don't you think you are making things unnecessarily complicated for yourself? What's wrong with using php for templating?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://devzone.zend.com/406/integrating-smarty-with-the-zend-framework/)?

Comment: Or [this](http://gediminasm.org/article/smarty-3-extension-for-zend-framework)?

Comment: @vascowhite Thaks for the input. I want to use Smarty because a) I really like the syntax and b) I just dont want to use php as a templating engine, because it leaves the possibility open to break the mvc in the template, whereas smarty does not.

Comment: @vascowhite I used the 1st link to get it running in the first place. The second link I  will check out as soon as I can. I found a similar implementation, that uses an approach with smarty functions [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/11/03/the-best-smarty-zend-view-helpers-solution/), but i really dislike the syntax.

Comment: Good luck with the project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions (only ideas, nothing so good):

1. Create a __toString() in Zend_Layout who returns null or empty string (big/ugly/worse workaround).
2. Create a variable modifier/filter who return null or empty string, so your call will be something like `{$this->layout()->setLayout('default')|noreturn}` (you can use it with other things too and `noreturn` can be called with an friendly name like `definition` or `define` to indicate the purpose of the instruction, but a workaround too)
3. Using the [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.assign) to build a expression who set all this thing to another var (workaround too).

Maybe this can give you some good ideas =)

Comment: I will try the modifier (2) as soon as I get to it.
1) is obvious, but i dont want to change any Zend classes. 3) is not really possible, as the View should be very general.